# String field being treated as numeric value?

Tags: business-objects, webi

My report is pulling data from a CSV on a network drive (long story, but source application is antiquated).

The field 'Docket Num' (=[DocketNum]) is configured in the Universe as a string, but the report appears to be interpreting it as a numeric value.

[Example of CSV content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tH4w.jpg)

[Example of report output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vy8H.jpg)

To troubleshoot the issue, I tried manually altering the contents of the CSV to remove the non-numeric characters:

[Example of altered CSV content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M55dB.jpg)

[Example of altered report output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8keTu.jpg)

The report then displayed as expected which seems to confirm that the report is having trouble interpreting the data type correctly.

Is there a function or cube transformation that I can apply to force it to return the string?